# List all days in a month (dates with day names)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to increment for each row day and show day name.

- 1.1.2014 Wednesday
- 2.1.2014 Thursday
- ...etc

How to make this?

App.js

```
App.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {

var g = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'];


var datastart = new Date(2014, 1, 1);
$scope.myDate = datastart;
$scope.myDays = g;
```

});

HTML:

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="MyDay in MyDays"> // for 1 to 31
                   <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ MyData | date:'EEEE'}}" />
                        </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: There's a `getDay()` method in `Date`. Notice, that `new Date(2014, 1, 1)` doesn't probably return what you think, months are zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct a table or Date in Javascript (be careful of your month length 28 - 31 ?) :

```
$scope.days = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
    $scope.days.push(new Date(2014, 1, i);
}
```

And then in your html file :

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="day in days">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ day | date:'EEEE'}}" />
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution to increment the day without needing to worry about the number of days in the month.

Here is an add day method that adds / subtracts the milliseconds of a day to the timestamp of a date

```
var dayInMS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var toNumber = function(n) {
    n = +n;
    if (!n) {
        n = 1;
    }
    return n;
};
addDay = function(date, n) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + (dayInMS * toNumber(n)));
};

var date = new Date(2014, 1, 1);
$scope.newData = addDay(date, 1);
```